# Android Development the new boston *Email*

Tags: java, android

I am on the 36th tutorial of thenewboston android app development on youtube. He has had us copy and paste our code (cause we are supposed to know how to do it by now). I copied and pasted it, didnt work so i tried typing it all out. Still didnt work. My R.id isnt working. I have already had problems with this before so i knew to check my XML file. and in there everything is crazy. I get an error everywhere i have android:layout_width="match_parent". Did some research and i guess that got updated to "fill_parent" changed that, now I get an error in my XML saying "error: ERROR parising XML: not well-formed (invalid token)". I have tried starting over mulitple times. cleaning project. Restarting. Triple checking my code. I dont know what im doing wrong. please help guys! Im going nuts!! Thanks in advanced.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:weightSum="100"
<ScrollView
    android:layout_weight="30"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <TextView 
        android:text="Email address(es):"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <EditText 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/etEmails"
        />          

    <TextView 
        android:text="Hatfull intro"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <EditText 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/etIntro"
        />

    <TextView 
        android:text="Persons name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/etName"
        />

    <TextView 
        android:text="Stupid things this person does:"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <EditText 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="etThings"
        />

    <TextView 
        android:text="What do you want to do to this person?"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <EditText 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/etAction"
        />

    <TextView 
        android:text="Hatefull Outro"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/etOutro"
        />

    </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="40">

    <Button 
        android:text="Send"
        android:id="@+id/bSentEmail"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    </Button>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="30">

    <AnalogClock 
        android:id="@+id/analogClock1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    </AnalogClock>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Also you have `fill_parent` and `match_parent` backwards. `fill_parent` was deprecated in favor of `match_parent`, although realistically it doesn't even matter as the constants are the same. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a `>` at the end of line 6:

change

```
android:weightSum="100"
```

to

```
android:weightSum="100">
```

Comment: and  `android:id="etThings"` was wrong. should have been `android:id="@+/etThings` But when i got the `>` placed i was able to debug the rest easily. thank you so much!